# Run python script every 5 minutes under Windows

Tags: python

I am having a simple python script scraping some data from html page and writing out results to a csv file. How can I automate the scraping, i.e. kick it off every five minutes under Windows.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Use Windows 'Task Scheduler'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into this link:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/

You'll need to change some settings in Windows Task Scheduler to run the script every five minutes, otherwise the above tutorial works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows i would suggest using Windows Task Scheduler, it's quite simple thanks to the UI and from there Trigger your Python code.

For a server environment like Linux you could set up a Cron task.