# Execute a script/file on a Webserver every 2 minutes (Python, .exe)

Tags: python, php, server

I wrote a Python script which I want to execute every 2 minutes. The script basically exports data and writes it into a .json file. Another script reads the data later and imports them into another system.

My question is, how can I execute the program every 2 minutes... I don't have any PHP skills, so I can't "translate" the program and create a simple cronjob on my webserver.

Is it possible with a Managed Server with Microsoft Server 2019?
Or is there any other possibility to do this?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215153/run-python-script-every-5-minutes-under-windows help?

Comment: Thank you! But the script must run 24/7. So I can't set up a simple cronjob on a client computer. That's why it should be executed on a server :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `time` module to sleep

```
import time
time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Thank you Princerawat! And do you know what Server I need? Can I execute the program on a Webserver or is it necessare that it is a Windows Server?

Comment: if it is python you can use it on any webserver

Comment: No, not really, there are tons of cheap webservers that allow php, php, and... php.

Comment: maybe you can try VPS. you can find cheap ones on digitalocean, vultr, etc. besides you will get to learn something